# How do I add a make target to a build configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I've added a `test` target to `makefile.targets` in an Eclipse C++ project. Now, I want it to be built as part of my Debug and Release build configurations so I can have my unit tests run as part of the normal build process.

How do I do this, given that I cannot edit the auto-generated `Debug/makefile` and `Release/makefile`?

Comment: Just add 'test' as a dependency to the main 'all' target.  So a line like 'all: test' in makefile.target will cause 'test' to added to 'all'.  If you need to sequence 'test', then you have to make it depend on the normal 'elf' name (or vice-versa).  You can add dependencies in the 'makefile.target'.  The rules will refer to files in 'Debug' or 'Release' depending on the build type.  You may use `TYPE=$(notdir $(CURDIR))` and then `$(strip $(TYPE))` to get the appropriate type of build.

Answer (score 2):

The pseudo-code below hopefully answers the question about target addition, and additionally addresses how to use variables in the makefile and source code.

It took me a day to figure this out using web resources, especially stackoverflow.com and eclipse.org forums. The Eclipse documentation for CDT is a bit vague on some points.

```
// pseudo-code for Eclipse version Kepler
if ("Project.Properties.C/C++ Build.Generate Makefiles automatically" == true) {
  // when using the automatically generated makefiles,
  //   use the -include's in the generated Debug/makefile
  cp <your makefile init statements> $(ProjDirPath)/makefile.init
  cp <your makefile definitions>     $(ProjDirPath)/makefile.defs
  cp <your makefile targets>         $(ProjDirPath)/makefile.targets
} else {
  // when using a makefile that you maintain, alter your own makefile
  cp <your makefile targets>         <your makefile>
}
// Additionally, you may want to provide variables for use in the makefile 
//   commands, whether it's your own makefile or the generated one:
//    Note that:
//    - "Preferences.C/C++.Build.Build Variables" and
//      "Project.Properties.C/C++ Build.Build Variables" 
//       are *NOT directly available* to the makefile commands.
//    - "Preferences.C/C++.Build.Environment" variables and
//      "Project.Properties.C/C++ Build.Environment" variables
//      *ARE available* to the makefile commands.
//    - To make "Build Variables" available to the makefile and source files,
//      add an environment variable as shown below. Especially useful are the
//      built-in ones visible when "Show system variables" is checked.

// assign the build system variable "ProjDirPath" as a *user preference*
"Preferences.C/C++.Build.Environment".AddKeyValue("ProjDirPath",
                                                  "${ProjDirPath}"}

// assign the build system variable "ProjDirPath" as a *project property*
"Project.Properties.C/C++ Build.Environment".AddKeyValue("ProjDirPath",
                                                         ${ProjDirPath}")
```

An example "makefile.init":

```
GREP := /bin/grep
```

An example "makefile.defs":

```
ifndef ProjDirPath
  $(error "ProjDirPath" undefined as a "make variable" or "environment variable".)
endif
```

The generated makefile Debug/src/subdir.mk extracts dependencies into 
the file ${ProjDirPath}/Debug/src/${ProjName}.d, but you need to add an extra target for initial generation of a dependency. You could add a target for an:

```
#include "automated_headers.h"
```

by adding targets to ${ProjDirPath}/makefile.targets.

An example "makefile.targets":

```
# targets to generate a header file
%/src/automated_headers.h: %/src/generate_headers.py $(external_library_info)
    @echo "Generating $@"
    %/src/generate_headers.py $(extrnal_library_info) $@

src/$(ProjName).o: $(ProjDirPath)/src/automated_headers.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Make Target` view if it's not already open. It has a `New Make Target` button.

Alternatively, highlight the name of the target in the makefile, right click, and go to `Make Targets -> Create...`.

Edit: I may have misunderstood your question. If you want the target to be built, when you click build, go to the build preferences and add it there.

Comment: OK, I do want to cause a target that I added to `makefile.targets` to be included in my build configurations. I'll clean up the question and try your suggestion. :)

Comment: Hrm, editing build configurations seems to be disabled for me, at least from the Projects > Build Configurations menu--Manage Build Configurations is greyed out. Any advice?

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, I don't use auto-generated makefiles myself, so I can't help you with this. I thought it would be similar to using manual makefiles, but no.